# How make post endpoint where data pass in request body using javax.ws.rs?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http, post

I have the next method im my service inteface

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response addNewWallet();
```

But this post method don't use body to post json on Web Service, the new wallet just generating on DAO layer and then transforms to json.

How can I create new wallet using, for example, Postman to send this wallet (as json) in post body?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON databinding technology, such as JSON-B or Jackson, to accomplish this. These libraries are capable of converting POJO<-->JSON data.

Once you pick one of these libraries, you can implement JAX-RS's [MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/javaee/8/#class=javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html&package=allclasses-frame.html) to tell JAX-RS to use these libs how to convert the incoming/outgoing objects. A sample implementation using JSON-B might look like this:

```
@Provider
@Produces({ "*/*" })
@Consumes({ "*/*" })
public class JsonBProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>, MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> clazz, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                           MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String stringResult = convertStreamToString(entityStream);
        return jsonb.fromJson(stringResult, genericType);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
            return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object obj, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                        MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String strData = jsonb.toJson(obj);
        jsonb.toJson(obj, entityStream);
    }
}
```

Note that if you're using an application server, this sort of integration will be provided automatically. Also, there are individual libs available for Jackson that do this same sort of thing so you don't need to write it yourself.

Once you have the MessageBodyReader/Writer registered, then you can simply send and receive POJO objects from your JAX-RS resource like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response addNewWallet(Wallet toCreate) {
  // add a wallet...
}
```

In the above example, when the JAX-RS endpoint receives JSON data as the message body, it will use the MessageBodyReader/Writer to automatically convert the incoming JSON data to a `Wallet` pojo, which will get passed into the `addNewWallet` method.